# count the same value of each row in a column

Tags: mysql, sql

In my sql I have a table like this below. In that table I have topicID which is not a primary key just to make it clear. I am struggling to write a script which can give a count of same topicID in the table.

```
topicID  |  description |  date     |
|  1     |    xyz      | 2018-11-11 |
|  1     |    xyz      | 2018-11-11 | 
|  2     |    xyz      | 2018-11-11 |
|  1     |    xyz      | 2018-11-11 | 
|  3     |    xyz      | 2018-11-11 |
|  3     |    xyz      | 2018-11-11 | 
|  2     |    xyz      | 2018-11-11 |
|  1     |    xyz      | 2018-11-11 |
```

For example:

```
topic Id    numberOfTime
   1              4
   2              2
   3              3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is [Group BY](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) expression. Try the following,

```
 select topicId as 'Topic Id' ,count(*) as 'Number of times' from my_table group by topicId
```